# Display 10 blog posts on first page and 9 thereafter

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm using the "bones" theme on WordPress. On my blog page I'm trying to have it with 9 blog posts displayed in 3 columns, but on the first page have 10 blog posts with the first (most recent) one being enlarged to span all 3 columns.

What is the best way to display 10 posts on the first page and 9 thereafter without messing up the pagination?

Here's my code: (I removed all the HTML and what-not because I assume it's not needed)

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $c++;
    if( !$paged && $c == 1){
        //code for the first post
    } else {  // THE REST: begin the code for the remainder of the posts ?>

<?php } 
endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really experimented with it as I don't have the page function set up - but try this

```
<?php 
$post = $posts[0]; $c=0;
$c++; if( !$paged && $c == 1){
$query1 = new WP_Query( array ('posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
if ($query1-> have_posts()) : while ($query1-> have_posts()) : $query1-> the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();} 
else{
$query2 = new WP_Query( array ('posts_per_page' => 9, 'offset' => 1 ) );
if ($query2-> have_posts()) : while ($query2-> have_posts()) : $query2-> the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); }?>
```